# comparing multiple columns in dataframe (more than 2)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'student': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                     'rank': [2, 2, 1],
                     'rank1': [3, 3, 2],
                     'rank2': [4, 2, 3]})
```

my code

```
import numpy as np

data['Diff'] = np.where((data['rank'] != data['rank1']) &
                        (data['rank1'] != data['rank2']), '1', '0')
```

requirement all the ranks must be different then 1 else 0 but I am getting  b also as 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the `rank` like columns, then use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) along `axis=1` to check for the occurrence of `N` unique values

```
r = data.filter(like='rank')
data['diff'] = r.nunique(1).eq(r.shape[1]).view('i1')
```

---

```
  student  rank  rank1  rank2  diff
0       a     2      3      4     1
1       b     2      3      2     0
2       c     1      2      3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()` and check if the lenght of the set constructed from all the column values == 3:

```py
data["Diff"] = (
    data[["rank", "rank1", "rank2"]]
    .apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 3, axis=1)
    .astype(int)
)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
  student  rank  rank1  rank2  Diff
0       a     2      3      4     1
1       b     2      3      2     0
2       c     1      2      3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `pd.Series.unique` with `let`

```
data['new'] = data.filter(like='rank').apply(pd.Series.unique,1).str.len().eq(3).astype(int)

Out[45]: 
0    1
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: diff compared to 0 would also only find consecutive duplicates no?